# Python: Fill 'na' in pandas column with random elements from a list

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill 'NA' in a pandas column by randomly selecting elements from a list.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pandas.DataFrame()
df['A'] = [1, 2, None, 5, 53, None]
fill_list = [22, 56, 84]
```

Is it possible to write a function which takes the pandas DF with column name as input and replaces all NA by randomly selecting elements from the list 'fill_list'?

```
fun(df['column_name'], fill_list])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create new `Series` with [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) and then replace `NaN`s by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(pd.Series(np.random.choice(fill_list, size=len(df.index))))
#alternative
#df['A'] = df['A'].combine_first(pd.Series(np.random.choice(fill_list, size=len(df.index))))
print (df)
      A
0   1.0
1   2.0
2  84.0
3   5.0
4  53.0
5  56.0
```

Or:

```
#get mask of NaNs
m = df['A'].isnull()
#count rows with NaNs
l = m.sum()
#create array with size l
s = np.random.choice(fill_list, size=l)
#set NaNs values
df.loc[m, 'A'] = s
print (df)
      A
0   1.0
1   2.0
2  56.0
3   5.0
4  53.0
5  56.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data_rnr['CO BORROWER NAME'].fillna("NO",inplace=True)
data_rnr['ET REASON'].fillna("ET REASON NOT AVAILABLE",inplace=True)
data_rnr['INSURANCE COMPANY NM'].fillna("INSURANCE COMPANY-NOT 
   AVAILABLE",inplace=True)
data_rnr['GENDER'].fillna("GENDER DATA- NOT AVAILABLE",inplace=True)
```